# Android CalendarView Display Specific Month

Tags: android, calendarview

Using CalendarView I need to display a particular month for when device is rotated. While I need to use "setDate" to set the date currently selected, I also need to display the month that was displayed which can be a totally different month to the date selected.  When the device was rotated, the user may be positioned on a completely different month to the month currently selected. I need to be able to position on that month in the new orientation. I have not been able to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
static final String STATE_DATA = "data";
private String mData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mData = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_DATA);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
        mData = "NewData";
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


     savedInstanceState.putString(STATE_DATA, mData);
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state

     super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Hope you aware of the lifecycle of Activity.

Comment: How does that set the CalendarView display to the correct month?